# spring data neo4j, how to access database by broswer when database is loaded by tomcat

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I use `<neo4j:config storeDirectory="/neo4j/target/data/db">` to config my neo4j database path,
and when tomcat started, the database files are **locked** by tomcat, and I can't start it using Neo4j official start tool, so how can I access my database in broswer like `localhost:7474`, or can spring connect a lunched neo4j server like mysql? and then I can access it through broswer.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with one graph instance from one place only. If you are using it via tomcat in your code you wont be able to start it from the community tool. You would need to stop your tomcat and then run the tool to view it in the browser.